# Probability of more than 1 robbery happening in 6 locations (naive definition)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Have the following question:

A city with 6 districts has 6 robberies in a particular week. Assume the robberies
are located randomly, with all possibilities for which robbery occurred where equally
likely. What is the probability that some district had more than 1 robbery?

Well, the model answer is quite simple - we are sampling locations with replacement, each robbery being a sampling event. Thus, we have 6^6 possible permutations how robberies could happen. 6! is the number of combinations when 1 location=1 robberry. so, result is 1 - 6!/6^6.

But I tried to solve it like this: we still have 6^6 possible permutations overall. Now, I think that there should be 5^6 permutations, when 6 robberies happen in 5 different locations (we leave 1 location out from sampling or sth like that), so 1 location is left out. Then, this event - all robberies happen in any location except 1 (my variant) => some location should have more than 1 robbery. It gives the probability: 5^6/6^6 - that is NOT what model answer says. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first of all, if you were to use this approach, notice that you have a choice of 6 locations where no robberies take place. So, at the very least you would need to multiply the number by 6, so you would get $6*5^6$ instead of just $5^6$.

OK, but that's still not right, because now there is a more subtle mistake:  you would be counting several distributions of robberies multiple times. For example, suppose we say that district A has no robberies. Then there are indeed $5^6$ ways to have 6 robberies in the remaining 5 districts. But, when you then do the same for district B and say there are *another* $5^6$ possible distributions there, then you are counting the distributions where there are no robberies in either district A or B twice. So, it will be less than $6*5^6$. Now, maybe some kind of complicated Exclusion-Inclusion principles you can get the actual correct formula out of this, but you and I know that it will end up equal to $1-\frac{6!}{6^6}$

Comment: If I rule 1 location already at the first step it means: first robbery happens in any location except one of them. If I again multiply by 5 for 2nd robbery - it means it again happens in any location except 1 of them. For the third robbery - multiply by 5 because again it will be 1 location out of 5 (1 location left without robbery) - so 5^6 will give all possible permutations of locations of robberies in 5 locations (permutation including 1 location will be ruled out). won't it?

Comment: @John No, that's what I tried to explain: the first robbery can happen in *any* of the 6 locations.  And when you get to the third robbery, there are only 4 locations left without a robbery, not 5. So the only time you have 5 locations left is for the second robbery.

Comment: But this is exactly the thing I don't understand - I would like to count permutations without 1 location. I artificially limit all robberies to only 5 locations in order to leave 1 location without robberies. And as a dual event - it also says that one of the locations should have had more than 1 robbery. So, all robberies happen in 5 locations (giving 5^6 permutations).

Comment: @John Ooooh, now I see what you are trying to do.  OK, then the problem lies elsewhere!  I'll update my answer.  Sorry for not initially not understanding what you are trying to do !

Comment: @John OK, I updated my Answer. Again, sorry for not immediately grasping what you were trying to do. It would indeed seem to make sense ... but I found the mistake.

Comment: Wonderful! I got it too now! Seems like it is harder to calculate than 6! I finally understood where the flaw was (recounting permutations)! Thanks =)

Comment: @John Great, glad I could help! :)